Can the verb “require” be followed directly by an infinitive or a gerund?
Can the verb require be followed directly by an infinitive or a gerund?
Ex) We require to know it.
We require knowing it.
Are they correct? Thank you.

The idiomatic version of this sentence is "We need to know it."  The meaning of "Require to know it" is intelligble but it sounds like a translation using a dictionary by someone who has not spoken much with native speakers and who has not read widely in English.

I would make the same criticism of the English writers who did use it, typically scientists and logicians and mathematicians who presumably had some objection to using the idiomatic "need to" in their formal writing.

The verb "require" takes a noun as its object.

We require a car.

A gerund is a form of noun so:

The car requires repairing.

is correct.
("The car requires a repair" is also correct because "repair" is a noun as well as a verb.)
An infinitive is not a noun, so "The car requires to repair" is not correct.
You may be confusing it with the passive form which does take an infinitive: "We are required to repair the car"
TLDR: Your first sentence is wrong, your second is correct.

You used to be able to say He requires to know... instead of He demands to know... / He insists on knowing... a century or two ago, but it's not really a suitable construction for learners to use today. An awful lot of meanings and syntactic affordances have changed over the centuries for require.

A good point, and I'd forgotten it.

So had I when I wrote a now-deleted comment saying OP's #1 was invalid! But I would strongly advise learners not to use #2 We require knowing it either. I don't find that an idiomatic combination of subject and verb with the "insist" sense - but I do happily endorse This requires fixing, so the basic construction works. I'd still advise learners to stick with This needs fixing / to be fixed, though.

The OPs actual example is a bit weird, which is why I substituted a different example to give the grammatical sense. But I'm not sure WHY "We require knowing it" is wrong, if it is wrong, rather than unusual; whereas "The car requires repairing" is clearly right..

I think the difference is that We require knowing is an "incorrect" way of saying We insist on knowing (active, with volition), whereas in The wall requires pointing there's no suggestion that the wall insists on being pointed. But my example rapidly gets a bit weird itself. I'm good with The car requires that it be repaired, but I'm not sure what I think of The wall requires that it be pointed (and I have serious misgivings about The wall insists that someone point it! :)

Require does accept infinitival clauses as complements, but only with an explicit subject. So “We require to repair the car” is not grammatical, but “They require (for) us to repair the car” is fine – it’s the active counterpart to the passive “We are required to repair the car”. It can also take a declarative content clause, of course: “They require that we repair the car” (often in the subjunctive).
